# How to use more CPU power in Proteus simulations

Tags: proteus

Labcenter's people wrote in the help of proteus that for increasing the time speed on real time simulations usually we need to reduce the frequency of clocks or the frequency of peripherals in case of microcontrollers because of the mixed simulation, including in the cases where are possible change the property of analog components from analog to digital, specifically the mixed simulation problem comes because normally the microcontroller simulations has some signal conditioning which involves analog simulation.

What if instead of that I simply increase the quantity of available cores to Proteus of the computer's CPU?

I don't know if that is possible or it has been done previously por Labcenter's team but the help doesn'r mention any of that matter as far as I've read.

Is there any hidden or unhidden (what I didn't see) setting for making available more CPU power or cores to Proteus?

I've ran it an example project which shows the warning of simulation is not running in real time because of high CPU load but when I go to the performance window of Windows 10 the the CPU is loaded to an average of 26% aproximatelly like shown in the attached image.

[image: Simulation running and CPU's computer load.]

Comment: I would have thought that if it can be made to run faster by using more cores they would make quite a point of telling you instead of hiding it away. If that's a quad core CPU it would suggest it's using one core only.

Comment: If it's fundamentally a single-threaded application, more cores won't help.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll keep using it that way then.

Comment: Errata: (I couldn't edit my previous comment again so I'm writing a new one). Making a rapid test after asign to proteus a single core seems to have improved the applications performance, during the time period that the example was ran it never appeared the warning message of "simultation no running in real time due to excesive CPU load". I need to thank you both for your answers and advices.